# Pysaprk parse complex json to rows

Tags: python, json, pyspark

I have the following json in a file:

```
{
    "code": 0,
    "msg": "OK",
    "sensors": {
        "258443": {
            "fieldname": "DeviceStatus2",
            "info": "Unlock Request",
            "id": 258443,
            "work": {
                "1623020526": {
                    "ts": 1623020526,
                    "te": 1623021124,
                    "lat": "-25.911997",
                    "lon": "28.169119"
                },
                "1623021393": {
                    "ts": 1623021393,
                    "te": 1623021453,
                    "lat": "-25.911997",
                    "lon": "28.169119"
                },
                "1623052154": {
                    "ts": 1623052154,
                    "te": 1623052783,
                    "lat": "-25.790348",
                    "lon": "28.308369"
                }
            }
        },
        "258441": {
            "fieldname": "Dis1",
            "info": "Door",
            "id": 258441,
            "work": {
                "1623021447": {
                    "ts": 1623021447,
                    "te": 1623035978,
                    "lat": "-25.911997",
                    "lon": "28.169119"
                },
                "1623052775": {
                    "ts": 1623052775,
                    "te": 1623058925,
                    "lat": "-25.790348",
                    "lon": "28.308369"
                }
            }
        },
        "258442": {
            "fieldname": "AnalogInput",
            "info": "Lock Fire",
            "id": 258442,
            "work": {
                "1623021453": {
                    "ts": 1623021453,
                    "te": 1623021633,
                    "lat": "-25.911997",
                    "lon": "28.169119"
                },
                "1623052783": {
                    "ts": 1623052783,
                    "te": 1623052962,
                    "lat": "-25.790348",
                    "lon": "28.308369"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to use pyspark to parse it into the following rows:

```
258443,DeviceStatus2,Unlock Request,258443,1623020526,1623021124,-25.911997,28.169119
258443,DeviceStatus2,Unlock Request,258443,1623021393,1623021453,-25.911997,28.169119
258443,DeviceStatus2,Unlock Request,258443,1623052154,1623052783,-25.790348,28.308369
258441,Dis1,Door,258441,1623021447,1623035978,-25.911997,-25.911997
258441,Dis1,Door,258441,1623052775,1623058925,-25.790348,28.308369
258442,AnalogInput,Lock Fire258442,1623021453,1623021633,-25.911997,28.169119
258442,AnalogInput,Lock Fire258442,1623052783,1623052962,-25.790348,28.308369
```

I have tried to use explode and arrays_zip but its failing.
How can I parse this json into rows?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a free coding service. _"I have tried to use explode and arrays_zip but its failing."_ - show us that code. You have to _make an honest attempt_, and then ask a _specific question_ about your algorithm or technique. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).

Comment: please explain the mapping. Which fields of the JSON are supposed to appear in your final csv output ?

Comment: BTW, if you can change the structure of the JSON : both `sensors` and `work` should be list, not struct, and using an ID as key make that the struct of the JSON is changing for each ID. keys should be the same in every json you have. just values should change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using IDs as key in a JSON is a very bad idea because it means your struct change all the time. Ideally, keys should remain the same and just values have to change.
But you can cheat a little bit using `MapType`.

you need to use this schema to properly acquire your JSON data in spark :

```py
from pyspark.sql import types as T

schm = T.StructType(
    [
        T.StructField("code", T.IntegerType()),
        T.StructField("msg", T.StringType()),
        T.StructField(
            "sensors",
            T.MapType(  # This map type allows any ID as key
                T.StringType(),
                T.StructType(
                    [
                        T.StructField("fieldname", T.StringType()),
                        T.StructField("info", T.StringType()),
                        T.StructField("id", T.IntegerType()),
                        T.StructField(
                            "work",
                            T.MapType(  # Same here
                                T.StringType(),
                                T.StructType(
                                    [
                                        T.StructField("ts", T.IntegerType()),
                                        T.StructField("te", T.IntegerType()),
                                        T.StructField("lat", T.StringType()),
                                        T.StructField("lon", T.StringType()),
                                    ]
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ]
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ]
)
```

Then, your dataframe should have this schema :

```py
df.printSchema()
root
 |-- code: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- msg: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sensors: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- fieldname: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- info: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- work: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- ts: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- te: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- lat: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- lon: string (nullable = true)
```

Then, simply using `explode` and `select`, you can achieve the desired output :

```py
df.select(F.explode("sensors").alias("key", "sensor")).select(
    "sensor", F.explode("sensor.work").alias("key", "work")
).select(
    "sensor.id",
    "sensor.fieldname",
    "sensor.info",
    "work.te",
    "work.ts",
    "work.lat",
    "work.lon",
).show()

+------+-------------+--------------+----------+----------+----------+---------+
|    id|    fieldname|          info|        te|        ts|       lat|      lon|
+------+-------------+--------------+----------+----------+----------+---------+
|258443|DeviceStatus2|Unlock Request|1623021124|1623020526|-25.911997|28.169119|
|258443|DeviceStatus2|Unlock Request|1623021453|1623021393|-25.911997|28.169119|
|258443|DeviceStatus2|Unlock Request|1623052783|1623052154|-25.790348|28.308369|
|258441|         Dis1|          Door|1623035978|1623021447|-25.911997|28.169119|
|258441|         Dis1|          Door|1623058925|1623052775|-25.790348|28.308369|
|258442|  AnalogInput|     Lock Fire|1623021633|1623021453|-25.911997|28.169119|
|258442|  AnalogInput|     Lock Fire|1623052962|1623052783|-25.790348|28.308369|
+------+-------------+--------------+----------+----------+----------+---------+
```

Comment: A quick clarification from general perspective, If I dont proivde the schema then also the result happens to be same. So how does schema helps? In what scenarios schema should be provided.

Comment: @PythonLearner In this specific case, we need a `MapType` because spark does not infer Map by default.

Comment: Even if it didn't infer **MAP TYPE** but I get the same result without providing the schema and directly using the explode part post reading the json. So is it providing some other befits as well

Comment: @PythonLearner please create a new question with your  issue. Comments should not be used for that